The length of all sg in sg_table after dma_map_sg is less than request?
I try to alloc 16G system memory by vm_mmap and get_user_pages_fast, and pass the memory to dma_map_sg, But the length of all sg after dma_map_sg is less than 16G, it will equal when i disable iommu. My test code as follow:
#include <linux/memblock.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>
#include <linux/mman.h>
#include <linux/dma-mapping.h>

#define __SIZE_TO_PAGE_NUM(a)   ((a) >> PAGE_SHIFT)
#define XFER_PAGE_NUM __SIZE_TO_PAGE_NUM(xfer->size)
#define MAX_PIN_SIZE SZ_1G
#define MAX_PIN_PAGE_NUM        __SIZE_TO_PAGE_NUM(MAX_PIN_SIZE)

static struct sg_table sgt;
static struct page** pages = NULL;
static int probe_status = 0;
static u64 addr = 0;
static u64 size = SZ_16G;

void dma_test_remove(struct pci_dev *pdev);
static struct pci_device_id dma_test_dev_id[] = {
        {
                PCI_DEVICE(0x1e3e, 0x2),
        },
        {}
};

static int dma_test_probe(struct pci_dev *pdev,
                             const struct pci_device_id *pent)
{
        u64 buf;
        u32 page_num;
        u32 index;
        int n;
        int ret;
        u32 page_num_pinned = 0;
    int i;
    struct scatterlist *sg;
    u64 dma_len = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count0 = 0;
        /* init dma*/
        ret = dma_set_mask(&pdev->dev, DMA_BIT_MASK(48));
        if (ret) {
                printk("dma_set_mask failed\n");
                return ret;
        }
        ret = dma_set_coherent_mask(&pdev->dev, DMA_BIT_MASK(48));
        if (ret) {
                printk("dma_set_coherent_mask failed\n");
                return ret;
        }

        // alloc va
        addr = vm_mmap(NULL, 0, size,
                                PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                                MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE, 0);
        if (IS_ERR(ERR_PTR(addr))) {
                printk("vm_mmap alloc va failed\n");
                return -EFAULT;
        }
        printk("alloc va success\n");

        page_num = size >> PAGE_SHIFT;
        pages = vmalloc(page_num * sizeof(struct pages *));
        if (!pages) {
                vm_munmap(addr, size);
                printk("vmalloc alloc memory failed\n");
                return -ENOMEM;
        }

        // pin memory
        buf = addr;
        while (page_num) {
                // n = min_t(typeof(n), page_num, MAX_PIN_PAGE_NUM);
                n = get_user_pages_fast(buf, page_num, FOLL_WRITE, (pages + page_num_pinned));
                if (n < 0) {
                        printk("pin pages failed %d\n", n);
                        goto unpin_dma_pages;
                }
                page_num_pinned += n;
                page_num  -= n;
                buf += (unsigned long)n << PAGE_SHIFT;
        }
        printk("pin pages success\n");

        /*create sg table*/
        ret = sg_alloc_table_from_pages(&sgt, pages, size >> PAGE_SHIFT,
                                        0, size, GFP_KERNEL);
        if(ret) {
                printk("alloc sg_table failed %d\n", ret);
                goto unpin_dma_pages;
        }
        printk("alloc sg table success\n");

        for_each_sg(sgt.sgl, sg, sg_nents(sgt.sgl), i){
                dma_len += sg_dma_len(sg);
        count0++;
        if (sg_dma_len(sg) == 0)
            count1++;
    }

    printk("count0 %d count1 %d\n", count0, count1);
        if (dma_len < size) {
                printk("dma len error in sg_alloc_table dma_len %llx size %llx\n", dma_len, size);
        }
        // dma map
        ret = dma_map_sg(&pdev->dev, sgt.sgl, sg_nents(sgt.sgl), DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL);
    if (unlikely(!ret)) {
                printk("dma map sg failed %d\n", ret);
        ret = -ENOMEM;
                goto free_sg;
    }
        probe_status = 1;
    dma_len = 0;
    i = 0;
    count0 = 0;
    count1 = 0;
        for_each_sg(sgt.sgl, sg, sg_nents(sgt.sgl), i){
                dma_len += sg_dma_len(sg);
        count0++;
        if (sg_dma_len(sg) == 0)
        {
            //printk("dma map sg len is 0\n");
            count1++;
        }
        }
    printk("count0 %d count1 %d dma_len %llx request len %llx\n", count0, count1, dma_len, size);
        if (dma_len < size) {
                printk("dma len error in dma_map_sg dma_len %llx size %llx\n", dma_len, size);
        }
        printk("dma map success\n");
        return 0;

free_sg:
        sg_free_table(&sgt);

unpin_dma_pages:
        for (index = 0; index < page_num_pinned; index++) {
                put_page(pages[index]);
        }

        vfree(pages);
        vm_munmap(addr, size);

        return ret;
}

void dma_test_remove(struct pci_dev *pdev)
{
        int index;
        if (probe_status)
                dma_unmap_sg(&pdev->dev, sgt.sgl, sg_nents(sgt.sgl), DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL);

        sg_free_table(&sgt);



        for (index = 0; index < (size >> PAGE_SHIFT); index++) {
                put_page(pages[index]);
        }

        if (addr)
                vm_munmap(addr, size);

        if (pages)
                vfree(pages);

        printk("remove dma-test module\n");
}
static struct pci_driver dma_test_pci_driver = {
        .name = "dma-test",
        .id_table = dma_test_dev_id,
        .probe = dma_test_probe,
        .remove = dma_test_remove,
};


static int __init dma_map_test_init(void)
{
        return pci_register_driver(&dma_test_pci_driver);
}

static void __exit dma_map_test_exit(void)
{
    pci_unregister_driver(&dma_test_pci_driver);
}

module_init(dma_map_test_init);
module_exit(dma_map_test_exit);

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, dma_test_dev_id);
MODULE_AUTHOR("zhanged");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("zhanged Test dma_map_sg for large size");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL and additional rights");

when i insmod this kernel module first time, dma_len equal 16G, but the dma_len  less than 16G if load the kernel module after the second time. I try to disable iommu by edit /etc/default/grub, This phenomenon will disappear no matter how many times I execute it.
my server info:

dma_test # lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble
dma_test # cat /proc/version
Linux version 6.8.0-48-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-010) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42) #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 14:04:52 UTC 2024
dma_test # cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic root=UUID=c8ffbdad-f578-4acd-a77b-320d315a9b80 ro quiet splash 0 intel_iommu=on memmap=20G!28G vt.handoff=7
dma_test # free -tg
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              27           3          18           0           5          23
Swap:              7           0           7
Total:            35           3          26
dma_test # lscpu
Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   16
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-15
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  BIOS Vendor ID:         Intel(R) Corporation
  Model name:             Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz
    BIOS Model name:      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz To Be Filled By O.E.M. CPU @ 2.8GHz
    BIOS CPU family:      198
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                165
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   8
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             5
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:   30%
    CPU max MHz:          4800.0000
    CPU min MHz:          800.0000
    BogoMIPS:             5799.77
    Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe sysca
                          ll nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmu
                          lqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_
                          timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow flexp
                          riority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt
                           xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp vnmi pku ospke md_clear flush_l1d arch_c
                          apabilities
Virtualization features:
  Virtualization:         VT-x
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                    256 KiB (8 instances)
  L1i:                    256 KiB (8 instances)
  L2:                     2 MiB (8 instances)
  L3:                     16 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):           1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):      0-15
Vulnerabilities:
  Gather data sampling:   Mitigation; Microcode
  Itlb multihit:          KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
  L1tf:                   Not affected
  Mds:                    Not affected
  Meltdown:               Not affected
  Mmio stale data:        Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Reg file data sampling: Not affected
  Retbleed:               Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS
  Spec rstack overflow:   Not affected
  Spec store bypass:      Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:             Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:             Mitigation; Enhanced / Automatic IBRS; IBPB conditional; RSB filling; PBRSB-eIBRS SW sequence; BHI SW loop, KVM SW loop
  Srbds:                  Mitigation; Microcode
  Tsx async abort:        Not affected


I have tried install some other linux kernel, but the question still exist. Only disable iommu(add intel_iommu=off to cmdline) can fix my question.
Is there are some wrong in my test code?
